# Is there a way to put an intro before the game starts?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to put an intro (like intro.jpg) after the "Powered by Unity" intro and I want the intro to be displayed for 2 seconds.

Comment: Please next time try something before posting and let us know what you tried. Check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your first scene is called `Game`.
Create a new Scene called i.e "Introduction".
In this scene, add your image element and assign it a script :

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Intro : MonoBehaviour {


    bool shouldGo = false;
    float timeout = 2.0f;

    void Update () {

        if (shouldGo) {

            timeout -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (timeout <= 0.0f) Go();
            return;

        } else {

            int percentageLoaded = (int)(Application.GetStreamProgressForLevel("Game") * 100.0f);

        }

         if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
            if (Application.CanStreamedLevelBeLoaded("Game")) shouldGo = true;
         }

         if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            if (Application.CanStreamedLevelBeLoaded("Game")) shouldGo = true;
         }

    }


    void Go() {

        Application.LoadLevel("Game");

    }


}
```

Then in `Build Settings`, add your new `Introduction`scene and move it to the 0 position by dragging on top of the list.

Comment: Thank you. Next time i will try before aaking. Thank you!